# Keyboard Shortcut for switching to Desktops #5 and higher

Tags: keyboard, macos

How can we create a keyboard shortcut to switch to desktops #5 and higher? Under preferences, seems like #4 is as high as we go

Comment: Did you make the Spaces first? Potential shortcuts appear as you create new spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The desktops you want to set in the shortcuts menu should exist when you open te preferences. When you add one with the settings screen open, it doesn't refresh the list.

Just open and close the preferences.

[image: keyboard shortcuts]